# Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit ISO image not downloading

Tags: iso

For last two days I've been trying to download the ISO image of Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, but after my browser has downloaded around 40 MB it fails to download further and finally it shows "failed" without any reason.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: I had no problem downloading the Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit iso image from downloads.ubuntu.com. The problem is not at Ubuntu's end.

Answer (score 4):

Try downloading the ISO image via torrent. Here [Alternative downloads](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads).

Answer (score 0):

If you really tried everything and your computer can't completely download the file, you can purchase the official Ubuntu installation stick. [Canonical Shop](https://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1206)

Otherwise I suggest to try the download with an other laptop, because it seems like this is a problem of the system you're using...